# Django makemigrations 1.8.18 ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field

Tags: python, django

Recently upgraded Django to 1.8 from 1.7. Taken a dump of the PRD DB into DEV. Don't care about any of the migrations in the DB for dev, so:

1. Delete migrations folders in my apps.
2. Delete all rows from django_migrations table.

OK, all good. Now, I just want to make a fake migration for the apps, and away we go. So I start with the top level app 'website'.

Running this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations website
```

Gives the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='HistoricalStock',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
            ('period_date', models.DateField()),
            ('close', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('open', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('day_high', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('day_low', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('change', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('average_gain', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('average_loss', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('rsi', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('true_range', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('average_true_range', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('price_average_true_range', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('thirty_day_constant_maturity_vol_skew', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, null=True, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10, blank=True)),
        ],
        options={
            'ordering': ['period_date'],
        },
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Industry',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
            ('group', models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40, verbose_name=b'name')),
            ('slug', models.SlugField(unique=True)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Sector',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
            ('group', models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40, verbose_name=b'name')),
            ('slug', models.SlugField(unique=True)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Stock',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
            ('ticker', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
            ('profile', models.TextField()),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
            ('broker_rating', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)),
            ('ranking_industry', models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)),
            ('ranking_industry_upper_percent', models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10, blank=True)),
            ('country', models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)),
            ('has_options', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ('current_stock_price', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('change', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('change_percent', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('open', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('day_high', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('day_low', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('ex_div_date', models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)),
            ('pay_div_date', models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)),
            ('earnings_date', models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)),
            ('vol', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('pe', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('mkt_cap', models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=40, decimal_places=0)),
            ('div_yield', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('div_amount', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('year_high', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('year_low', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('day180pc', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('day360pc', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('instpct', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('insidepct', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('earnings_share', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('fifty_ma', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('two_hundred_ma', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('std_dev', models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)),
            ('stats_period', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
            ('last_refreshed', models.DateTimeField(null=True, editable=False, blank=True)),
            ('industry', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, blank=True, to='website.Industry', null=True)),
            ('sector', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, blank=True, to='website.Sector', null=True)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='industry',
        name='sector',
        field=models.ForeignKey(to='website.Sector'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='historicalstock',
        name='stock',
        field=models.ForeignKey(to='website.Stock'),
    ),
    migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
        name='historicalstock',
        unique_together=set([('stock', 'period_date')]),
    ),
]
```

Looks fine, 4 models, with a couple of FK to models in the same file.

Then, run the fake:

```
python manage.py migrate website --fake
```

It goes nuts:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field keyedcache.Stock.sector: website.Sector
```

It's saying that the app keyedcache is not finding a reference to the model Sector? What has keyedcache got to do with it?

Keyedcache is an app I have installed.

If I run:

```
python manage.py migrate keyedcache --fake
```

It says nothing to migrate.

And round and round you go.

I have done this hundreds of times in Django 1.7 with no problems at all. Something has changed in 1.8 that is causing this.

Whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a path full of pitfalls that many others have travelled before you. The first thing to do is to clear up your migrations again. Then clear up all stale `.pyc` files. This step is very important.

After that you need to do

```
./manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

For all your apps. Then only should you run

```
./manage.py migrate --fake
```

Comment: It worked - bizarre. I removed the .pyc files and started all over again, and everything ran. No idea!

Comment: Glad it's sorted out. All the best with your project